# Why iam getting error code 1064 in WHEN else STATMENT and enable to run query

Tags: mysql

Write a query to return Yes if the patient’s age is greater than 40 else return No.

```
select patient_id,patient_name
  CASE
  when age < 40 then 'Yes'
  else 'NO'
  from patients;
```

When I write the above query for `case when else` statement, I get a 1064 error.

Comment: Apart from your syntax error on the missing `END`, the logic in your query is wrong. You should assign Yes when age > 40, not the opposite.

Comment: Storing age isn't a great idea either..

Answer (score 2):

Missing `END` and a comma. Also, as another user mentioned, you should change the comparison operator.

```
select patient_id
     ,patient_name
     ,CASE when age > 40 then 'Yes' else 'NO' END as col_name
from patients;
```